# Given a cubic function, how do I find the parametric equation?

Tags: parametric, cubics

I want the parametric equation of a cubic function which is: 
f(x) = 0.00000358x^3-0.00263x^2+0.498*x-11.5

[Click here to see the function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFkQ7.png)

Is there any 'easy' way to solve this?

Comment: I think in question x instead of t.

Comment: I corrected it. Thanks

Comment: The easiest way to parametrize a one single variable function is $\left(\,x,\,f(x)\,\right)\; ,\;\; x\in\Bbb R\;$ ...what else?

Comment: So in this case its p(x)=(x,0.00000358x^3-0.00263x^2+0.498*x-11.5) ?? Or am I totally wrong haha..